# How do we prove conditional probability distribution for stochastic equation

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

## Back Ground

I read books "Diffusion Models" written by Okanohara Daisuke.
I cannot understand bleow problem.

Please tell me how to prove this problem.

## Problem

We consider below stochastic differential euqation.
\begin{equation}
dx=f(t)xdt+g(t)dw
\end{equation}

Then we get conditional probability distribution $p(x(t)|x(0))$.
\begin{eqnarray}
p(x(t)|x(0))&=&\mathcal{N}(s(t)x(0),s(t)^2\sigma(t)^2I)\\
s(t)&=&\exp\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(\xi)d\xi\right)\\
\sigma(t)&=&\sqrt{\int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{g(\xi)^2}{s(\xi)^2}d\xi}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: https://mathlog.info/articles/IooWy76ZFWkMXeijmEh3

Comment: Apply Itô's lemma to the quantity $y = \frac{x}{s(t)}$ and integrate.

Comment: thank you for answering question ! can we get solution if we use Ito lemma ?

Comment: Yes, precisely the one you wrote above.